# chrome don't follow the redirect after XMLHttpRequest

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, xmlhttprequest

my web are built on flask

I enter page1 by GET , generate data then send the data back by XMLHttpRequest 
 POST  in script of page1.html

```js
  var form = document.getElementById('process_form');

  form.onsubmit = function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();     

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.open('POST', '/main/page1', true);

     xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

     var data = JSON.stringify(data);
     xhr.send(data);
  };
```

then I redirect to another page in page1 views

`#process the data
    redirect(url_for('main.page2'))`

I can see the code of page2 view did execute and debug log

but the chrome browser still hold the page1,do not follow the redirect